# Need to get an array of all Id's in a firebase collection

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase

Have the method below that extracts the Id's from the firebase collection and pushes it to an array, BUT it makes each document into an array. In other words- if i have 100 documents in the collection - it makes 100 arrays inside the array IDarray. I just need one array to keep it more efficient. Maybe:)

```
     db.collection('Customers')
     .orderBy('createdAt', 'asc')
     .get()
     .then((data) => {
                      let IDarray = [];
                      data.docs.forEach(doc =>{
                      IDarray.push(+doc.id);
                      });
       return [IDarray];
     })
```

I can certainly make this work but if anyone knows of a better way so the system is not generating all the extra arrays it would be appreciated. (Back story: the IDarray is being generated as int because my Id's for the collection are a number sequence)
Cheers!

Comment: i'm not sure but try change  return [IDarray]; to  return IDarray;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
  db
    .collection("Customers")
    .orderBy("createdAt", "asc")
    .get()
    .then((data) => {
      let IDarray = [];
      data.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        IDarray.push(+doc.id);
      });
      return IDarray;
    });
```

It works just fine for me.

Or here's an ES6-y way of doing it:

```
  db
    .collection("Customers")
    .orderBy("createdAt", "asc")
    .get()
    .then(({ docs }) => docs.map(({ id }) => +id));
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you don't need another array wrapper for the return value:

```
    return IDarray;
```

Notice no square braces.  Just return the array as-is.